# Can't get a line on a graph from a .csv file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I am trying to generate a plot from a .csv file.

My .csv file contains the following data and it is named `HeightsAndWeights.csv`:

[image]

To generate the plot I use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz} % To generate the plot from csv
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Allows to place the legend below plot
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} % Allows to enter the units nicely

\sisetup{
   round-mode          = places,
   round-precision     = 2,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=\linewidth, % scales the plot to the line width of the sheet.
                grid=major, % displays a grid
                grid style={dashed,gray!30}, % grid style
                xlabel=Heights $h$, % set axis labels
                ylabel=Weights $w$,
                x units=\si{cm},
                y units=\si{kg},
                legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north}, % put the legend below the plot
                x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east}, % display label sideways
                ]
                \addplot % add the plot from the table
                table[x index=1,y index=2,sep=comma]{HeightsAndWeights.csv};
                \legend{Plot}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Plot of the data from the file containing students' heights and weights.}
    \end{center}    
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What should I correct, add or remove?

---

Updated after a comment:

Here is the full list of packages I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel} 
\usepackage{dirtytalk} % to allow quotations with \say{}
\usepackage{amsmath} % to allow removal of equation numbering.
\usepackage{graphicx} % to allow use of images and pictures.
\usepackage{subcaption} % to allow the use of multiple images.
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % to allow colored tables.
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule.
\usepackage{siunitx} % for formatting units and values.
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % for generating tables form .csv files.
\usepackage{tikz} % for generating plots from .csv files.

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % for legends below the plot.
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} % for using measuring units.

\sisetup{ % setting up the siunitx package
   round-mode=places, % round numbers
   round-precision=2  % up to the second digit
}
```

---

Update 2:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{file.csv}
   Peter, 150, 45
   Jason, 134, 39
   Stefan, 139, 41
   Noa, 132, 38
   Liv, 137, 36
   Beti 135, 34
\end{filecontents*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! where is your `csv` file. without it you cant draw your table. Also you need to load `pgfplots` package.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! I'm using overleaf and I've uploaded the file there. I'll include the full list of packaged I'm using, now.

Comment: You should provide table data in your document example. Without it we cant test you MWE(Miniml Working Example). From package we need only to your problem relevant ones.

Comment: I am uploading the table data now.

Comment: Make a single MWE not 3 sniplets we have to combine.

Comment: Your example contains many errors, don't ignore errors. For example there is a comma missing in the CSV, there are no options called `x units`, `sep=comma` should be `column sep=comma` etc.

Answer (score 1):

As daleif already stated in his (several) comments: After removing all the (spelling) errors, the MWE works as expected ...

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
    \begin{filecontents*}{HeightsAndWeights.csv}
       Peter, 150, 45
       Jason, 134, 39
       Stefan, 139, 41
       Noa, 132, 38
       Liv, 137, 36
       Beti 135, 34
    \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{units}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid=major,
        grid style={dashed,gray!30},
        xlabel=Heights $h$,
        ylabel=Weights $w$,
        x unit=\si{\centi\metre},
        y unit=\si{\kilogram},
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,
        },
        x tick label style={
            rotate=90,
            anchor=east,
        },
        table/col sep=comma,
    ]
        \addplot table [x index=1,y index=2] {HeightsAndWeights.csv};
        \legend{Plot}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]